# Why is image being laid out repeatedly in this background

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uppy

I have this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/expanding-cards-with-extra-7by4n?file=/src/components/AnimatedList.jsx)

I can't understand why the image here looks like this: repeatedly being displayed please advice. This only happens when image ratio is 1:5

[image]

This code is this in AnimatedList.jsx:

```
    <Flipped
      flipId={`media-${fileId}`}
      shouldFlip={shouldFlip(fileId)}
      delayUntil={createCardFlipId(fileId)}
    >
      <div
        className="media"
        style={{
          backgroundSize: "contain",
       
          backgroundImage: "url(" + file.preview + ")",
        }}
      />
    </Flipped>
```

And the styles.scss

```
  .media {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 16px;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the background repeat in your scss class.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```